# Difference between two minimization problems

Tags: analysis, optimization, maxima-minima, least-squares, numerical-optimization

Assume you are given a matrix A and a vector b.

Is there a difference between

$min_p\|p\|^2$ such that $Ap=b$

and

$min_p \| Ap - b \|^2_2$?

In both cases you want to find the minimal $p$ which suffices $Ap=b$, right?
Is it just different notation?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming that $Ap=b$ has a solution, the first case will find the shortest $p$ such that $Ap=b$ and the second will find some $p$ such that $Ap=b$. In the more interesting case when the equation $Ap=b$ has no solutions then they are even more different: the first is infeasible and the other solves linear regression. So I would say they are quite different.